# iPhone X scaling issue, can we scale existing apps to fullscreen mode without an app update

Tags: ios, iphone-x, app-update

All my existing apps are not scaled to iPhone X, is there any way to make them to full screen without an update.
It will be really helpful if we don't have to go to the hassle of upgrading all the apps again.

And if not what are the options of doing it.

It is reminding me of days back to iPhone 6.

[image]

Comment: If you had adopted autolayout and launch storyboards a couple of years ago when it was first recommended then you probably wouldn't have to do anything.  Since you haven't used a launch storyboard you will need to release an update to support the full screen of iPhone X.

Comment: Simply add an extra launchscreen image for iphone X and resubmit.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can’t get your app out of letterboxed mode without at the very least updating your app to use a launch storyboard (and building it against the iOS 11 SDK).

Also, just doing that might not make your app work right on iPhone X — unless all your UI is built from only basic uses of system view controllers, you’re likely to have at least a few issues where you need to tweak your layout to respect safe areas. (Otherwise you end up with UI hiding under the notch or rounded corners.)